# Applying conditional style on click on single element in collection

Tags: css, reactjs, loops, state

I have a functional component which maps over a set of value and displays a row of items. I want to attach a click handler on each of these which changes the class on just the clicked item. Now, my brain is all over-farted and my current solution adds the class to all the rendered items (well, of course. It's inside a loop):

```js
function AvailableSizes(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="sizes">
      <h4>Available Sizes</h4>
      <div className="d-flex mb-4 flex-wrap flex-row">
        {props.sizes.map(size => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
              key={size}
              className={`size m-2 mt-4 p-2 shadow ${active ? 'current' : ''}`}
            >
              {size}
              <span>Your size</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image: This is what I'm getting]

This is what I want:

[image: This is what I want]

I am sure there is some obvious way to do this, but the hour is late and I am currently quite dumb, so please guide me towards the light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your divs are sharing the same state as a boolean, instead of using a boolean for active it should be a unique string/number, for example the size.

```
function AvailableSizes(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="sizes">
      <h4>Available Sizes</h4>
      <div className="d-flex mb-4 flex-wrap flex-row">
        {props.sizes.map(size => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => setActive(size)}
              key={size}
              className={
                `size m-2 mt-4 p-2 shadow ${active === size ? 'current' : ''}`
              }
            >
              {size}
              <span>Your size</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is quite simple. just separate size in another component.

```
function SingleSize({ size }) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div 
       className={`size m-2 mt-4 p-2 shadow ${activeProp ? 'current' : ''}`}
       onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    >
      {size}
      <span>Your size</span>
    </div>
  )
}


function AvailableSizes(props) {
  return (
    <div className="sizes">
      <h4>Available Sizes</h4>
      <div className="d-flex mb-4 flex-wrap flex-row">
        {props.sizes.map(size => <SingleSize key={size} size={size} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this issue because of `active` here is the `AvailableSize` component state, not state for each single size.